# Images in blockquotes

Tags: discussion, etiquette, images, blockquote

Is there any official etiquette for placing images in blockquotes? I usually just put them in the post without blockquotes. Also, sometimes edits are just made to add blockquotes to images. This image is out of blockquotes:

[image: Example out of blockquotes.]

This image is inside of the blockquotes:

> [image: Example in the blockquotes.]

Which is preferred?

Comment: If you are including an image from another site then it should be quoted as per [How to reference material written by others](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Otherwise it's down to personal taste.

Answer (score 3):

If it is a quote from somewhere else, I always use block quotes, also around images. If the image has a white background, I usually also add block quotes for visibility reasons. The image you used in your question is a good example: when does the image end? It is unclear unless you add the block quote border.

There is no official etiquette for this, and it really depends on the site if adding block quotes around images is appreciated or not.